# If I open Unity tweak tool, it mentions com.canonical.unity.webapps is missing

Tags: unity, 15.04, unity-tweak-tool

following message appears:

[image]

If I press okay, nothing happens. What do I have to do?

Comment: What if you run it from a terminal? `unity-tweak-tool`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the necessary packages. From terminal:

`sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-common`

Now try to execute tweak tool.

```
sudo unity-tweak-tool
```